# Windows Media Player 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I know there is a way to install Windows Media Player 9 and 10 in Windows 7 32bit.

Is there a way to install Media Player 7 in Windows 7 32bit?

Please don't mind the reason.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: You can't. [Windows Media Player 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player#Release_history) is only on Win95/98/2000/ME, not even available in XP. However WMP 8 already has compatibility with XP if you want to use compatibility mode.

Comment: "Please don't mind the reason." - the 'reason' could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - telling us what the reason is may help people to find another solution.

Comment: There was a patched wmp 7 for win7 but not my language. (I need korean)

Comment: No the reason is that I like wmp 7 than wmp 12

Comment: Your question makes no mention of that requirement (Korean language support).  Which will be tough due to the fact language support has significantly changed over the years.  You might simply be out of luck due to the age of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here: https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=36484

Install WMP7 on XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10.

Korean language works too.